# How does bootstrap's way of using sass maps work?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

Bootstraps writes on its documentation: `To modify an existing color in our $theme-colors map, add the following to your custom Sass file:`

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #0074d9,
  "danger": #ff4136
);
```

But how does this work internally? I always thought that maps in sass are immutable, which means that the content of a map cannot be changed. In my opinion I have to do something like this to override some values in a map:

```
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, (
    "primary": #0074d9,
    "danger": #ff4136
));
```

But bootstrap's solutions seems to work, too. Why? What am I missing? What did I not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in the bootstrap git repo the answer is just like you assume.
[link to repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/4ae6a29b1237818db71ed284139071c3f3ea8aa3/scss/_variables.scss#L78)

```
$theme-colors: () !default;
// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "primary":    $primary,
    "secondary":  $secondary,
    "success":    $success,
    "info":       $info,
    "warning":    $warning,
    "danger":     $danger,
    "light":      $light,
    "dark":       $dark
  ),
  $theme-colors
);
```

Comment: But in the docs it says that you can add colors to the map like described above. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#modify-map How is this possible?

Comment: Yes, correct $theme-colors is empty, marked as ! default and merged with the predefined

Comment: Do you need some more explanation on this topic? Otherwise marking the answer as correct would be appreciated.